# Lining up bootstrap columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a menu and an area that will contain text. My goal is to align the left edge of the word "Two" in the menu with the word "Four" in the text area. I thought using bootstrap and column offsets it would be easy, but it doesn't quite line up. I don't understand why, shouldn't the column classes and their offset counterparts have the same amount of margin and padding?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2">One</div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">Two</div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">Three</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10">
                <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-1">
                    Four
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please create a working demo.. It will give a better understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `.col-*-*` classes have `padding: 0 15px;`, that pairs up with `.row`s `margin: 0 -15px`. So you will need to provide another `.row` as parent for the second level of `.col-*-*`s:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-1">
          Four
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please notice that the nested `.col-*-*`s inside `.col-xs-10` will have their width relative to their parent and will not be equal with the ones one level up.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to align it with `two` with `four` then just wrap `four` inside one div with class `<div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-1">`

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      
       
       </head>
       <body>
       
     

<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2">One</div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">Two</div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">Three</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            
                <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-1">
                    Four
               
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra div in text area (2nd div with class row). Please remove that and use col-xs-offset-2

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2">One</div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">Two</div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">Three</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">

            <div class="col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-1">
                Four
            </div>

    </div>
```